# Вывод изображения в шаблон Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Добрый день, пробую сделать сайт на Django, хочу вывести на главную страницу кейсы с их превью, но тестовый сервер Django каждый раз отвечает 404 ошибкой. 
Django 1.9

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Case(models.Model):
    case_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    case_preview = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.case_name
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

**urls.py (который лежит в директории проекта, а не приложения)**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^landing/', include('landing.urls', namespace="landing")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views import generic

from .models import Case

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'landing/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'case_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Case.objects.all()
```

**index.html**

```
    {% if case_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for case in case_list %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ case.case_preview.url }}"/>
        <li>{{ case.case_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No cases are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Перерыл уже все форумы и документацию по Джанго, но решения так и не нашёл

Comment: Какой url генерируется в img src?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/media/images/2.jpg

Comment: Картинка реально лежит в BASE_DIR/static/media/images/2.jpg ? BASE_DIR правильно задан?

Comment: BASE_DIR имеет такой вид: 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: Папка static лежит в корне каталога, по соседству папкой приложения и проекта, manage.py и тд.

Comment: Операционная система какая?

Comment: Windows 10 ..........

Comment: При этом путь к изображению на диске верен:
>>> c = Case(case_name="Pic", case_preview="images/2.jpg")
>>> c.save()
>>> c.case_preview
<ImageFieldFile: images/2.jpg>
>>> c.case_preview.path
'C:\\Users\\Oskin\\Desktop\\pyProject\\uni\\static\\media\\images\\2.jpg'
>>> c.case_preview.url
'/static/media/images/2.jpg'
>>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наконец, нашёл решение проблемы - не использовать вложение папки media в static

**Было так:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/media/'
```

**А надо так:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```